# Realizar una consulta con LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp

```html
var query_actualizar = from x in ctx.banner
   let orden = ctx.banner.Where(y.id_banner == id_banner).First(y=> y.orden)
   where x.orden > orden
   select x;


foreach (banner ord in query_actualizar)
{
   ord.orden = ord.orden - 1;
}
```

Buen día quisiera hacer una consulta en LINQ:
SQL=>Update BANNER set ORDEN = ORDEN - 1  where ORDEN > (select ORDEN from BANNER where ID_BANNER = 18)

Al realizar la consulta me sale este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega tu codigo elizabeth, sera mas facil ayudarte y explica bien que es lo que necesitas

Comment: Intenta con `let orden = ctx.banner.Where(y.id_banner == id_banner).Select(y=>y.orden).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con tu consulta original es que `First`lo que espera es un condicional que cumpla el registro que quieres devolver. Hay varias opciones de hacer lo que pides, una es:

```
var query_actualizar = from x in ctx.banner
        let orden = ctx.banner.First(y=> y.id_banner == id_banner).orden
        where x.orden > orden
        select x;
```

Otra

```
var query_actualizar = from x in ctx.banner
        let orden = ctx.banner.Where(y.id_banner == id_banner).Select(y=>y.orden).FirstOrDefault();
        where x.orden > orden
        select x;
```

Ahora mismo no puedo probarlo, pero creo que cualquiera de las dos te debería funcionar. Si no es asi comentamelo.

Answer (score 1):

**Edito con la nueva información**

Prueba usando el método `FirstOrDefault` para obtener el primer elemento de la secuencia que cumpla con la condición:

```
var query_actualizar = from x in ctx.banner
            let orden = ctx.banner.FirstOrDefault(y => y.id_banner == id_banner).orden
            where x.orden > orden
            select x;
```

Comment: ok,probare, gracias

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola,Santiaguito, probe tu código, y me salio el siguiente error, envió la imagen, por favor alguna idea de como corregir esto?, gracias

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Espero que te funcione ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Holas Pikoh y Santiaguito, me salio con este código, Gracias!.

```html
var query_actualizar = from x in ctx.banner
        let orden = ctx.banner.First(y=> y.id_banner == id_banner).orden
        where x.orden > orden
        select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que seria conveniente primero evaluar si el resultado de la consulta con firstordefault es diferente de nulo, antes de invocar el Where. Dentro del ensamblado de la librería. Indica:

```
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     source or predicate is null.
```